# Getting Error when trying to run python code on zapier

Tags: python, zapier

I have the following address:

```
556_StreetName_Ave_CityName_11111
```

I want to use code to trim off the last part, `_Ave_CityName_11111`

so basically I want to remove anything with the last 3 underscores.

Here is my code:

```
output = "_".join(input['street_name'].split("_")[:-3])
```

but I get an error:

```
Bargle. We hit an error creating a run python. :-( Error: 
'unicode' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

Here is what my setup looks like in Zapier:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

output = {'street_name': "_".join(input['street_name'].split("_")[:-3])}

This actually is the code that allowed it to work if anyone needed help.

Thanks to nedbat on IRC phython channel for help!!

Comment: In order for the output of the code step to be useable in later steps of your Zap, `output` must by either a dictionary or a list of dictionaries.